# Clean development pattern for UITableViewCell & UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a NIB that contains a UIView that acts as a navigation view, and a UITableView. The NIB refers to a UITableViewController as its owner.

I want to keep my concerns separated: my cells will all manage their own deeper interactions, but if, say, I want to present a `UIImagePickerController`, I need to do so with the `UIViewController`.

My understanding traditionally is that delegation is the best option for this brand of architecture, but my `UITableView` class is managing the presentation of the cells, which are, they themselves, managing their own interactions. So am I to delegate to the tableview (which is not a viewcontroller), which delegates to the UIViewController? How do I do something like this so that it's the most unassuming possible?

Answer (score 1):

So, I solved this. Turns out a good approach is something like this:

1) The cell will have a protocol. This protocol will feature methods that express a wish for the resident view controller. To be more specific:

```
/* .h file of cell */
@protocol LoItemViewCellDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
- (void)cell:(LoItemViewCell *)cell wantsToPresentViewController:(id)viewController;
- (void)cell:(LoItemViewCell *)cell wantsToPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet;

@end
```

2) The cell *must* have access to a view controller directly via its delegate. Otherwise you're going to create a sandwich of logic that will become unruly. (e.g. cellview->tableview->viewcontroller)

3) You then call this method in your cell wherever you need it called:

```
/* Inside some method in cell .m */
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:sourceType];
imagePicker.delegate = self;

[self.delegate cell:self wantsToPresentViewController:imagePicker];
```

4) Your delegate is then free to implement these methods in whatever manner it wishes.

```
/* Delegate view controller */
- (void)cell:(LoItemViewCell *)cell wantsToPresentViewController:(id)viewController
{
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

In this way, you're only passing along the stuff the cell simply is unable to handle itself, while everything else (control logic, etc.) remains with the cell. So, for instance, in this example, I was passing a UIImagePickerController to my delegate to merely *show*, while I was doing all of the management of that controller inside of my cell, since my cell was the only piece of code that explicitly gave a damn what the picker wanted to do.

Very clean, I very much recommend this approach.